# How to get text of link that inside td in HTML Table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following structure of row in my table:

```
<tr class="mattersRow">
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="16">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose QB</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu"> … </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Note: I use bootstrap library*

I need to set to every `<td>` that has text inside "" (empty), or "Choose QB" class='danger'.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("#tblMatters .mattersRow td").each(function () {
      if ($(this).html() == "" || $(this).innerHTML == "Choose QB")
      {
           $(this).addClass("danger");
           flag = true;
      }
});
```

Of course, `$(this).html() == ""` works great, but how to set "danger" class to the `<td>` with **Choose QB**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `:contains()`<sup>[doc](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)</sup> and `:empty`<sup>[doc](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)</sup> selectors :

```
$('#tblMatters .mattersRow')
    .find('td:contains(\'Choose QB\'),td:empty')
    .addClass('danger');
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/a84CW/.

Answer (score 3):

`addClass` accepts a function as an argument, and within that function you have access to the currently iterated `td` element, and can check what it contains :

```
$("#tblMatters .mattersRow td").addClass(function() {
    var txt = $.trim( $('a', this).text() );

    return txt.length === 0 || txt == 'Choose QB' ? 'danger' : '';
});
```

If you're only trying to check the text inside the anchor, you should specify that in the question ?

Comment: Do you have other elements inside that TD with content, or in other words, shouldn't you probably just target the anchor only ?

Comment: @Bryuk - I made an edit to the answer, that should solve any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('td').addClass("danger");
```

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
$("#tblMatters .mattersRow td").filter(function () {
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    return txt.length === 0 || txt === 'Choose QB';
}).addClass("danger");
```

or check text of anchor tag

```
$("#tblMatters .mattersRow td a").filter(function () {
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    return txt.length === 0 || txt === 'Choose QB';
}).closest('td').addClass("danger");
```

---

This should work for both

```
$("#tblMatters .mattersRow td a").filter(function () {
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    return $(this).closest('td').text().length === 0 || txt === 'Choose QB';
}).closest('td').addClass("danger");
```

Comment: This is how to set class, Thanks, but how to find that (this) contains "Choose QB"

Comment: Haha. Now Choose QB works, but Empty td doesn't... Of course, I can combine your code and my, but will be great if it will works together...

Comment: OK. Summary for right now:
1st - works only for EMPTY
2nd - works only for Choose QB
3rd - doesn't work for anything

Comment: @Bryuk i missed `a` in 3rd one try one more time updated .Than i;m done.

Comment: Thanks, wared gave good and simple code=) But your help was good!

Comment: Actually your code looks like it should works, but for unknown reasons it doesn't

Comment: @Bryuk yeah made a lil change in  3rd one might work now . Hope so .

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).text().trim() === 'Choose QB'`